# Subset specific rows by first two strings

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
ID        value
1    package ‘glue’ was built under R version 3.6.2
2    Attaching package: ‘data.table’
3    Attaching package: ‘purrr’
4    Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
5    The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’
6    package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.6.2
```

If value starts with Attaching package (rows 2,3,4) I want to cut the rest of it after second word and leave unique. So, desired result is:

```
ID        value
1    package ‘glue’ was built under R version 3.6.2
2    Attaching package:
5    The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’
6    package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.6.2
```

How could i do that. I know that i should use regular expression:

```
\\S+\\s+\\S+
```

But how to do the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(value = gsub('(^Attaching package:).*', '\\1',value)) %>% 
group_by(value) %>% filter(ID == min(ID))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   value [4]
     ID value                                              
  <dbl> <chr>                                              
1     1 package ‘glue’ was built under R version 3.6.2     
2     2 Attaching package:                                 
3     5 The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’
4     6 package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.6.2
```

Using stringr, str_remove, str_replace and look behind:

```
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(value = str_remove(value, '(?<=Attaching package:).*')) %>% group_by(value) %>% filter(ID == min(ID))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   value [4]
     ID value                                              
  <dbl> <chr>                                              
1     1 package ‘glue’ was built under R version 3.6.2     
2     2 Attaching package:                                 
3     5 The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’
4     6 package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.6.2  

df %>% mutate(value = str_replace(value, '(^Attaching package:).*', '\\1')) %>% group_by(value) %>% filter(ID == min(ID))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   value [4]
     ID value                                              
  <dbl> <chr>                                              
1     1 package ‘glue’ was built under R version 3.6.2     
2     2 Attaching package:                                 
3     5 The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’
4     6 package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.6.2
```

Comment: @french_fries, have added stringr solution, please let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
df$value <- sub("(Attaching package:)(.*)", "\\1", df$value)
```

You can define the part you want to omit as a capturing group and *not* refer to it in `sub`s replacement argument, thus effectively removing it.

To remove the dups, use `duplicated`:

```
df <- df[!duplicated(df$value),]
```

Answer (score 0):

I throw in a solution with the rebus package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rebus)
library(stringi)

df <- dplyr::tibble(ID = c(1:6),
                    value =c("package ‘glue’ was built under R version 3.6.2","Attaching package: ‘data.table’","Attaching package: ‘purrr’","Attaching package: ‘dplyr’","The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’","package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.6.2" ))

pattern <- START %R% "Attaching package:"

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(NEW = ifelse(stringi::stri_detect_regex(value, pattern), "Attaching package", value)) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct(NEW)

  NEW                                                
  <chr>                                              
1 package ‘glue’ was built under R version 3.6.2     
2 Attaching package                                  
3 The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’
4 package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.6.2
```